# How can I train tesseract OCR using only images of text in a different font?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to train tesseract OCR using using only images of the text in that font as I can't find the font file anywhere online. When I run it normally, there are lots of errors from swapping V for Ұ, A as 4, and so on.

I have tried many image preprocessing techniques and it still yields the same result. I have a sample of the text attached below.

[Sample font image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5aUW.jpg)

Although it might not be useful, here is my code for the text extraction:

```
def text_extraction(text_img_input):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (r'C:\Users\p-IN-CHE7-ptsintern\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR'
                                             r'\tesseract.exe')
    # pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

    # Few image pre=processing techniques
    norm = np.zeros((text_img_input.shape[0], text_img_input.shape[1]))
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(text_img_input, norm, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    denoise_img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(norm_img, None, 10, 10, 7, 15)

    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(denoise_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    thresh_img = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # edges_img = cv2.Canny(image=thresh_img, threshold1=500, threshold2=500)

    # cv2.imshow("Processed Image for Text Extraction", gray_img)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    my_config = r"--psm 6 --oem 3"  # Operation modes and Engine modes
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh_img, config=my_config)

    # print(type(extracted_text))

    return extracted_text
```

Do help me in this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I commented the edge detection technique as it gave me worse results.